# Should adding a constructive comment fail an audit?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, review-audits

I have just [failed this audit](https://superuser.com/review/first-posts/605488) for adding a comment.

After having **carefully** read the question and the answer (which was in the first post review) I noticed that the answer ends with the following **incomplete** footnote:

> *Almost; filesystem choice is correlated with OS. Most Linux users use different FS than

I added the following comment:

> Your last sentence is incomplete ...

So that the OP could edit and fix the problem. It is **not** something I could have fixed myself.

If I wasn't a perfectionist paying such careful attention I would have passed the audit.

**Feature Request**

Making constructive comments on questions or answers should not cause a failed audit.

Please discuss.

Comment: I coulda sworn the behaviour was the other way around before ._.

Comment: Related: [Clicking "Add comment" fails review audit](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/188885)

Comment: Sadly it happens all the time